# How to serialize a view object in android

Tags: java, android

I have a view object that needs to be serialized to store in a database, and then retrieved later

```
public class MachineView extends View implements Serializable {

    String name;
    int age;

    public MachineView(String name, int age, Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);



        int x = getWidth();
        int y = getHeight();
        int radius;
        radius = 50;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        //paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextSize(x / 2);

         ...

    }
}
```

The only problem is that the methods I am using to serialize objects only work for simple objects( i.e. objects that can be condensed to key value pairs )
below are serialize and read object methods:

```
 //Serialize object 
 public static byte[] getSerializedObject(Serializable s) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
        byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();

        return result;
    }

    //read object 
    public static Object readSerializedObject(byte[] in) {
        Object result = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(in);
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            result = ois.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = null;
        } finally {
            try {
                ois.close();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It seems that i can convert the object into a byte array, but every time i read the object back it returns null

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine for me:

```
import java.io.*;
class Foo implements Serializable {
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Foo [x="+x+"]";
    }

    int x;
}
class Bar implements Serializable {
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Bar [foo="+foo+"]";
    }

    Foo foo;
}
public class Soxx {
    public static byte[] getSerializedObject(Serializable s) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos=null;
        try {
            oos=new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(s);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                oos.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {}
        }
        byte[] result=baos.toByteArray();
        return result;
    }
    //read object 
    public static Object readSerializedObject(byte[] in) {
        Object result=null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(in);
        ObjectInputStream ois=null;
        try {
            ois=new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            result=ois.readObject();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            result=null;
        } finally {
            try {
                ois.close();
            } catch(Throwable e) {}
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Foo foo=new Foo();
       foo.x=42;
       Bar bar=new Bar();
       bar.foo=foo;
       byte[] bytes=getSerializedObject(bar);
       Object object=readSerializedObject(bytes);
       System.out.println(object);
    }
}
```

outputs: Bar [foo=Foo [x=42]]

Comment: It works for simple objects but my class extends the view class which I am getting a null object back

Comment: i get a: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:106)
 at Soxx.readSerializedObject(Soxx.java:36)
 at Soxx.main(Soxx.java:56)' if i make Foo not implement serializable, so maybe one of yours is not serializable. persisting a view sounds like a bad idea, maybe use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern instead

Comment: You can't serialize a view class, that's just impossible, in theory you can, but the context might not be valid after de-serializing it for usage.